# How to display name instead of id in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

Im using visual studio with ASP.NET Core web App (.NET 6.0).Im using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 19 as database. Currently, i ran a problem where it display the id instead of name in book index.

I have category table in the database and show it in drop box

[image]

But when I show product detail in the index, the category become ID of the category

[image]

here is my code: https://github.com/thorgia1702/FPTBook

I have tried make the category name become the FK key in the book table in the Migrations file but have not success

Comment: "Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 19" <-- SSMS is a tool, not a database server.

Comment: You probably need a category navigation property in your book model, to represent the foreign key relationship correct so that EFCore will pick it up.

Comment: Might you please [edit] your question to add enough code to reproduce the problem **in the question itself**?  As explained in [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254428), questions asking for help with off-site code are off topic for Stack Overflow.  If you need help trimming your code down for the question, [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) can help.

Comment: Could you show your code how you diaplay your category list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I test your project, and I have the idea like below, could you try the below code?

1. Remove this line from your .csproj file, read [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/adding-model?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio#build-the-app) to know more:

`<Nullable>enable</Nullable>`

In BookController:

1.change the index action to add [.Include](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/eager#eager-loading) to use the Include method to specify related data to be included in query results. :

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
        {
            return View(await _context.Books.Include(x=>x.Category).ToListAsync());
        }
```

2.Change the post create action like your create action in CategoryController:

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("Id,Title,ReleaseDate,Price,CategoryId")] Book model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                _context.Add(model);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }
            ViewData["CategoryId"] = new SelectList(_context.Set<Category>(), "CategoryId", "Name",model.CategoryId);
            return View(model);
        }
```

3.result:

[image]

Comment: You are welcome:) Glad to hlep.

Comment: Where can I find the .csproj file? thx a lot

Comment: @TrầnQuangKhải Double left click your project https://i.stack.imgur.com/GL6hB.png .

Comment: its still not working-its still display id instead of name, do you have any contact link so I can talk to you

Comment: @TrầnQuangKhải  I'm sorry, according to the rules of the forum, we can't give you contact information, but you can ask your questions here, and we will help you solve them. "ts still not working-its still display id instead of name, " it's strange. In your book index, I see you use`@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Category.Name)`, so it should display name.

Comment: OMG IM SO FKIN DUMB !!!!

Comment: Hi @Trần Quang Khải , any update? If my answer help you resolve your issue, could you please accept as answer?

Comment: Tks bro, I have finished the application. Thank Qing Guo for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue with this method is that you should include the foreign object. The reason is that `ToListAsync()` materialises the query, and if you don't call Include, the category data will not load.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
{
     return View(await _context.Books.Include(b => b.Category).ToListAsync());
}
```

I also found that when you add a new book, you should use the `CategoryId` instead of `Category`.

```
var category = await _context.BookCategories.FindAsync(model.CategoryId);
```

[image]